# Why loader triggers two times after zoom out OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I have a method that is called by click. Itretrive the layers features as points and renders them:

```
  drawPointLayer(layer: LayerNode) {
    const { id } = layer;

    if (!this.vectorLayers.has(id)) {
      let { icon, zIndex } = layer;
      const layerConfig = this.getLayerConfig(id);
      const { pointIcon } = this.configService.config;
      const pathAttributesSelection =
        this.configService.config.pathAttributesSelection;
      const format = new GeoJSONOl();
      const source = new VectorSource({
        format,
        loader: (extent: Extent, resolution: number, projection) => {
          const url =
            this.configService.config.backendurl + `tile?layers=${id}`;
          this.http
            .get(url, { withCredentials: true })
            .subscribe((response) => {
              for (const [, geojson] of Object.entries(response)) {
                const features = format.readFeatures(geojson);
                source.addFeatures(features);
              }
            });
        },
        strategy: bboxStrategy,
      });

      source.on('addfeature', (e: VectorSourceEvent) =>
        addfeatureCallback(e.feature, layer, layerConfig)
      );

      this.clusterSource = new Cluster({
        distance: this.configService.config.distanceCluster ?? 100,
        source,
      });

      this.clusterVector = new VectorLayer({
        source: this.clusterSource,
        style: (feature) =>
          styleIconFeatureFunction(
            feature,
            icon,
            {
              pointIcon,
              pathAttributesSelection,
            },
            this.baseHref
          ),
      });

      this.clusterVector.setZIndex(zIndex ?? Infinity);
      this.mapService.map.addLayer(this.clusterVector);
      this.pointLayersSource.set(layer, source);
      this.addVectorLayer(id, this.clusterVector);
    }
  }
```

There is a significant issue when user zoom out the map the request is sent twice in loader function:

```
this.http.get(url, { withCredentials: true }) {}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You are using bboxStrategy and have changed the extent by zooming out.  If the url does not use the extent you should use the default strategy all.

Comment: I got, but why it sends two the same requests by one event (zoom out)? Do you offer change strategy on default?

Comment: I have removed the strategy, the same result!

Comment: I have the same problem, which means my features get drawn twice.